# How can I use an app I bought for my iPhone also on my iPad?

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

I have a IPhone 4S with TOM TOM installed (bought from Google Play), I now need the app to be copied to my IPad. Is there anyway to do this with out buying another TOM TOM app.

Comment: How did you buy an iOS app from Google Play?

Comment: Google Play Store is for Android devices and not for iOS.  So, with all due respect, I have my doubts that you bought it through the Play Store and successfully installed it on the iPhone in the first place.  Could you have bought it from the App Store instead?

Answer (score 1):

Apps bought in the iOS App Store can be installed in several iOS devices. Just make sure that you are logged into the App Store with the same Apple ID on both devices, then open the Store app, select the "Purchased" tab and search for the app.

Comment: It may be important to clarify that not _all_ apps work on iPhone and iPad, though in this particular case it appears that TomTom apps do work on both. Anyway, it seems the OP is confusing stores in the first place.